# How can I determine if a msoPlaceholder is a picture?

Tags: powerpoint, office-interop

I have a case (PowerPoint COM API) where Shape.Type == msoPlaceholder. The shape is a picture. How can I verify that it is a picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ContainedType

e.g. for a msoChart

```
oplc.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoChart (will return True / False)
```

Per the docs here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.placeholderformat.containedtype

Comment: Unfortunately no. It can also be set to msoPlaceholder and in that case might be a picture, chart, textbox, table, etc.

Comment: Interesting. It appears that a placeholder has a placeholderFormatType and it can be ppPlaceholderChart, ppPlaceholderPicture etc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.placeholderformat

Comment: Also, found this which seems promising https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-powerpoint/ppplaceholderobject/87a43302-7e14-4558-9720-581802389315

Comment: ContainedType solves this - thank you! Put that as your answer and I'm happy to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this works for me:

```cs
if (selectedShape.Type == MsoShapeType.msoPicture || selectedShape.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType == MsoShapeType.msoPicture) 
{

}
```